# .htaccess not working as it should

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url

I wanted to divert www.mydomain.com/alpha/ to www.mydomain.com/.

So I did following in .htaccess file:

```
#RewriteCond $1 !^/gazelle/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /gazelle/$1 [L]
```

Because of this now all other sub-directories are not working now.

For Example: www.mydomain.com/beta is not working now.

I am stuck on this for some time now. Any help on this would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because your `RewriteRule` is matching everything.

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/alpha/(.*)$ /$1
```

(or possibly omit the leading `/` in `/alpha`… I don't remember)

Answer (score 0):

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^alpha/([^/]+) /$1 [NC]
```